# iOS: UIButton background image getting removed for button in custom uitableviewcell on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have a uibutton in my custom table view cell which has different background image for a button for different cell. As soon as i start scrolling, random cells which were out of scope removes their background image. I have two button with two background image but it is always doing for one of them

[image: Here is an example]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
...
PlayerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerCell"];
    if(cell == nil) {

        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PlayerTableViewCell class]])
                cell = (PlayerTableViewCell *)currentObject;
        }
    }
numberImage = [self getUserImage:[self._collectionsNewGame[indexPath.row -1] objectForKey:@"hostBirthday"] isSign:false];
            signImage =[self getUserImage:[self._collectionsNewGame[indexPath.row -1] objectForKey:@"hostBirthday"] isSign:true];
cell.numberButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:numberImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.signButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:signImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
...
...
}
```

Please Help

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the buttons in the code. What is cell.numberButton and what is cell.signButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"playerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"playerCell"];
```

Comment: That solved icon from not appearing but it is showing in a different place?

Comment: I have started caching cells which kind of solved this issue. I will mark this as right answer